# Get icon of root window to be used by second window tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I was wondering if there is anyway to get the ico file of one window and use it in the same window, without getting to know the icon location.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap('img/icn.ico')
top = Toplevel()

root.mainloop()
```

Here I want `top` to have icon of `root` without saying `top.iconbitmap()` or `top.iconphoto()`, the closest ive got is `top.tk.call('wm','iconbitmap')` but I dont know what is to be done with this as i couldnt find a understandable documentation.

Why dont I want to use `iconbitmap()`, its basically that, with `tkinter.messagebox` you can see the messagebox automatically inherit the icons from the parent widget. I was trying to duplicate this effect. Where if the icon is the default tk icon, then show blank icon or else show the custom icon.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Try passing `True` to first argument of `iconphoto()`.

Answer (score 1):

*[I'm using links into the core Tk documentation here. It's much more accurate than the Tkinter docs for most things, and Tkinter is mostly an obvious thin wrapper around it.]*

You don't want [`wm iconbitmap`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M45). That's been effectively obsolete for decades; it uses an object class — `bitmap` — that's not relevant these days as it is monochrome and uses the weirdest format. (Filenames need to be preceded by `@` to make them work.)

Instead, you want to manipulate the [`wm iconphoto`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M50) of the toplevel windows concerned. These take true photo images (there are many image file formats you can load into them) and you can share them easily.

```python
# Load the image from the file; can also use PNG and other formats
my_image = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")

# Apply the image as the icons
first_toplevel_window.iconphoto(False, my_image)
second_toplevel_window.iconphoto(False, my_image)
```

Note that how the icon is displayed can vary wildly; it's not under your control.

Comment: But i dont have control over what the user chooses, like what if user chooses `bitmap`, but what i want is like without any addiotonal options or any setting automatically `messagebox` uses the icon of the parent window, how could that be?

Comment: Don't bother to give them the option. Or if they insist on doing it, let them deal with the consequences.

Comment: Its a feature i want to add, not an option for them. Thats why this Q was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iconphoto()` and set the first argument to `True`, then the same icon will be used for future created toplevels as well:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

icn = tk.PhotoImage(file='my-icon.png')
root.iconphoto(True, icn)

top = tk.Toplevel(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its like im making a module, so i dont have control over how the user will be setting their icon, what if its a `iconbitmap`? What i was looking for was a similar effect like the `messagebox` where without passing any argument or anything extra, they automatically get the icon of the parent window

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `default` instead of the `bitmap` (or first) argument, the icon will automatically be used on all `TopLevel` windows:

```py
root.iconbitmap('img/icn.ico')         # icon set only on root
root.iconbitmap(bitmap='img/icn.ico')  # same as above
root.iconbitmap(default='img/icn.ico') # icon set on root and all TopLevels
```

Comment: That is true, but basically that is summed up in the other answers